# run a common method in all child classes

Tags: javascript, inheritance

my code setup is following:
sender.js

```
function Sender () {}

Sender.prototype.sendData = = goog.abstractMethod;
```

userinfosender.js

```
// @implements {Sender}
class UserInfoSender {
...

sendData(...) {...}
...
}
```

documentcontentsender.js

```
// @implements {Sender}
class DocumentContentSender {
...

sendData(...) {...}
...
}
```

I have ~20 xxxSender classes and I want to run a common function `cleanDataBeforeSend()` in all of them.

A slow way is to invoke `cleanDataBeforeSend()` all existing child classes, but new child classes created in the future might forget to call it.

What is the recommended way to achieve that?

Comment: A method is called on instances, not on classes. Are you saying you have 20 instances of all these subclasses?

Comment: I have 20 classes, e.g. ImageSender.js, ..., VideoSender.js

Comment: Probably you should not have those. Instead, create 20 *objects*. Put them into an array and loop over them.